# Keras custom layer and custom loss function - need to preserve state

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Background: Text summarization using extractive method.

The article I'm following - [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8344797).

**Edit 1** link to [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fc2GYdHcewXZRS-pU1ZDqntKKjulvFlx)

The last layer in my network does classification using feature extraction from several inputs.

**Inputs**: (? meaning batch size)

1. d = document_embeddings shape = (?, 400)
2. s = sentence_embeddings shape = (?, 10, 400)
   (explanation - 10 sentences per document)
3. h_state  = h_state of the LSTM that produced the document_embeddings of shape (?, 10, 400) (explanation - 10 is the timestamps in the LSTM corresponding to the 10 sentences in each document, 400 is the size)

**Outputs:**

1. 1/0 per sentence so shape is (10,1)

In the last layer I use those inputs to compute features:

```
C_j = Wc * s_j
M_j = s_j.T * W_s * d
N_j = s_j.T * W_r * tanh(o_j), 
P_j = W_p * h_state
```

O_j is the summary representation of the document. and is calculated by summing the multiplication of each sentence_embeddings so far by it's probability to be in the summary.

```
for i in range(j-1):    
    sum += S_i * prob_in_summary(S_i)
```

This prob_in_summary for sentence i is computed by:

```
sigmoid(C_i + M_i - N_j + P_j + b)
```

Now. The loss function to minimise of the entire model is the negative log-likelihood of the observed labels (pseudo code)

```
  loss(Wieghts, bias) = 
  for doc.. 
      for sentence.. 
        sent_label * log(prob(sent_label == 1 | S_emb, O_j, D_emb)) + 
       (1-sent_label) * log(1-prob(sent_label==1 | S_emb, O_j, D_emb))
```

My questions are:

1. I do not know where to enter this loss function probability calculation given keras.
2. How do I define the label if what I get is probability out of the sigmoid? I need something like "if prob>0.7 decide 1 else 0"
3. Where do I compute O_j per sentence? I need to preserve some sort of state inside the layer.. but what I get to the layer is matrix of sentences and not one by one...

My code so far:

Custom layer:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        self.W_c = self.add_weight(name='W_c', shape=(1,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        self.W_s = self.add_weight(name='W_s', shape=(1,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        # self.W_r = self.add_weight(name='W_r', shape=(1,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        self.W_p = self.add_weight(name='W_p', shape=(1,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        # self.bias = self.add_weight(name='bias', shape=(1,), initializer='uniform',trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end


    def call(self, x):
        assert isinstance(x, list)
        document_embedding, sentences_embeddings_stacked, state_h = x

        content_richness = self.W_c * sentences_embeddings_stacked
        print("content_richness", content_richness.shape)

        print("sentences_embeddings_stacked", sentences_embeddings_stacked.shape)
        print("document_embedding", document_embedding.shape)
        print("document_embedding_repeat", K.repeat(document_embedding, 10).shape)
        novelty = sentences_embeddings_stacked * self.W_s # TODO transpose, * K.repeat(document_embedding, 10)
        print("novelty", novelty.shape)

        print("state_h", state_h.shape)
        position = self.W_p * state_h
        print("position", position.shape)

        return content_richness

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
        shape_a, shape_b, shape_c = input_shape
        # TODO what to put here? needs to be (?,10,1) or (?, 10) because 1/0 for each sentence in doc and there are 10 sentences
        return [(shape_a[0], self.output_dim), shape_b[:-1]]
```

Custom loss:

1. Do I need custom loss? or is there negative log-likelihood of the observed labeled in keras?
2. How do I compute y_pred inside model given the function to compute prob_in_sentence (where do I put it and where and how I implement the for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. had to treat batch size in side my custom layer. also some stacking and splitting.

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.W_p = self.add_weight(name='W_p',
                                   shape=(400,),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        self.W_c = self.add_weight(name='W_c',
                                   shape=(400,),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)

        self.W_s = self.add_weight(name='W_s',
                                   shape=(400,),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)

        self.W_r = self.add_weight(name='W_r',
                                   shape=(400,),
                                   initializer='uniform',
                                   trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        def compute_sentence_features(d, sentences_embeddings_stacked, p_j, j, sentences_probs):
            s = sentences_embeddings_stacked[:, j]

            c = s * self.W_c
            m = s * self.W_s * d  # missing transpose

            o = 0
            if j == 0:
                o = sentences_embeddings_stacked[:, 0] * 0.5
            else:
                for i in range(0, j):
                    o += sentences_embeddings_stacked[:, i] * sentences_probs[i]

            n = s * self.W_r * K.tanh(o)  # missing transpose
            p = self.W_p * p_j
            return c, m, n, p, o

        def compute_sentence_prob(features):
            c, m, n, p = features
            sentece_prob = K.sigmoid(c + m - n + p)
            return sentece_prob

        document_embedding, sentences_embeddings_stacked, doc_lstm = x

        O = []
        sentences_probs = []
        for j in range(0, 9):
            c, m, n, p, o = compute_sentence_features(document_embedding, sentences_embeddings_stacked, doc_lstm[:, j], j, sentences_probs)
            print("c,m,n,p,o", c, m, n, p, o)
            sentences_probs.append(compute_sentence_prob((c, m, n, p)))
            O.append(o)

        sentences_probs_stacked = tf.stack(sentences_probs, axis=1)

        dense4output10= Dense(10, input_shape=(400,))(K.sum(sentences_probs_stacked, axis=1))

        output = K.softmax(dense4output10)  # missing bias
        print("output", output)
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0][0], self.output_dim
```